# Why my kivy app is not showing it content?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having problems with my code, the app seems to work, but do not show it content.
I don't know why it's not showing the content.
this is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class entry(Screen):
    pass


class secret(Screen):
    pass


SM = ScreenManager()
SM.add_widget(entry(name="entry"))
SM.add_widget(secret(name="secret"))


class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SM


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreenApp().run()
```

and my kv file

```
<entry>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Label:
            text: "Enter the password"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Enter"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "secret" if password.text == "love" else "Screen 1"


<secret>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Label:
            text: "You have reached my secret"
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "entry"
```

what do I'm doing wrong? is any problens with de python or the kv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        SM = ScreenManager()
        SM.add_widget(entry(name="entry"))
        SM.add_widget(secret(name="secret"))
        SM.current = 'entry'
        return SM
```

There will be an error if you don't input 'love' in the textbox, as it calls for Screen1, but you have not defined Screen1